Conditionally making environment content disappear
I am working on project from which I want to produce both an answer key and a solutions manual to a long list of questions (I am also producing the problem sheet from this project as well). The problems and solutions are stored in their own tex document, which I use \input{} to put into the solutions manual/answer key.
I put each solution in this document as the argument to a \solution command, which is defined something like this:
\newcommand{\solution}[2]{
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hideSolution}}
  {The answer is #1.}
  {The answer is #1. Solution: #2}
}
% #1 = answer, #2 = solution

I have imported ifthenelse and set the condition of hideSolution at the top of each document to determine whether the solutions will appear as just the answer, or the entire solution in that document.
However, this will not do; it is quite important to me that the solution is in an environment and not a command, as I have asymptote code within the solution that will not render if it is put in a command. So I would like to still conditionally make #2 appear, except now "#2" is actually the content of the environment. I tried to use the comment package to accomplish this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{comment}

\newboolean{hideSolution}
\setboolean{hideSolution}{true}

%define environment solution
\newenvironment{solution}[1]
  {\ifthenelse{\boolean{hideSolution}}
    { The answer is #1.
      \begin{comment}
    } %if hideSolution = true, I want the content inside the environment to disappear 
    { The answer is #1. Solution:} %otherwise, I want the content to appear
  }
  {\ifthenelse{\boolean{hideSolution}}
    { 
      \end{comment}
    }
    { }
  }

\begin{document}
What is $2+2$?
\begin{solution}{$4$} We have $2+2 = 4$.
\end{solution}

\end{document}

This code does not even compile – I believe this has to do with the fact that I am trying to use \begin{comment} inside the definition of the solution environment. I have also tried using the versions package, and got a similar compilation failure which I believe to be directly related to the fact that I'm using it in the definition of an environment.
How can I make the content in an environment disappear conditionally? I would ideally like to stick to using ifthen, but I would be glad to hear any solution.
I am new to this site, apologies for any mistakes in this post. Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX.SX!

You can't use comment as the argument of a command (it's based on verbatim mode).
My suggestion is to absorb the environment's content with the +b argument type and typeset it conditionally.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{hideSolution}
\setboolean{hideSolution}{true}

%define environment solution
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{m+b}{%
  \par
  The answer is #1.
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{hideSolution}}{}{\par#2}
}{\par}

\begin{document}

What is $2+2$?
\begin{solution}{$4$}
We have $2+2 = 4$.
\end{solution}

\bigskip
\setboolean{hideSolution}{false}

What is $2+2$?
\begin{solution}{$4$}
We have $2+2 = 4$.
\end{solution}

\end{document}



Thanks for the reply! The disappearing part works with this solution, but the asymptote diagrams won't render within the environment – they don't render when they're inside of the argument of any command. What can I do about that? (I know I could always just upload them as pictures. But I don't want to resort to that yet.)

@BennyWang I see no asymptote diagram in your post

You can also set up a boolean variable. I use \answers when I want to add answers to a review or exam. You can use whatever latex formatting you want to between \ifanswers and either \else or \fi. Once the questions and answers are written you can toggle between showing answers and not by toggling between \answerstrue and \answersfalse at the top of the page.
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifanswers
\answerstrue
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is the first question.
            \ifanswers
            This is the first answer
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw [domain=0:2*pi] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \else
            \vspace{\fill} 
        \fi
    \question This is the second question.
        \ifanswers 
            This is the second answer
        \else
            \vspace{\fill} 
        \fi
    \end{questions}
\end{document}


Thanks for the reply! The output of this works just as I need it to. However, I was wondering if there was a way to package all of the if/else logic into an environment definition so that I don't have to type out the same logic every single time (see the example in the OP post for what I mean by this.)

I believe this can be achieved using the scontents package or more directly using the new enumext package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,enumext}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumext}[save-ans=test, show-ans=true]
  \item This is the first question.
        \begin{anskey*}
        This is the first answer
        
         \begin{tikzpicture}
           \draw [domain=0:2*pi] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
         \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{anskey*}
  \item This is the second question.
        \anskey{This is the second answer}
\end{enumext}
    
\printkeyans[columns=1]{test}
 
\end{document}


The show-ans key controls the display of answers, reading the documentation is highly recommended.
